# Sending sine wave from MATLAB and reading on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, matlab

I am working on timing issues associated with sampling data at high rates and storing it on an SD card (ADC delays, clock drifts and file I/O time). For this experiment, I thought of sending a sinusoidal wave to an analog pin on the Arduino Uno, and have the board read the samples. Can I eliminate the need for a function generator and instead use the Matlab Support Package for Arduino to send the sinusoid to the Arduino? (I guess this would mean two programs simultaneously, a Matlab program for generation of a sinusoid and an Arduino sketch for reading and writing.)
I'm new to Matlab, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So do you have a problem implementing the arduino sketch or the matlab code? How are you going to output the analog signal? Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I would like to know if running two such programs at the same time is possible. Also, I am going to write the output on an SD card, hence the Arduino sketch will just have analogRead() and file.print() functions. I'm not sure how to go about with the Matlab code, (again only if running two programs is possible).

Comment: No, it's not possible. Only 1 program at a time. Use a second Arduino. An please mind, that the Arduino Uno does not have a real DAC. If you use `analogWrite()` it will output a PWM wave, not an actual analog voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. The Arduino Uno has no analog outputs to start with and,
as you guessed, it cannot run two programs at the same time.

Maybe you should search for a solution of the *initial* problem instead.
You should be aware that you cannot get consistent timings with
`analogRead()`. You will have to read the datasheet of the ATmega328p,
especially the section dedicated to the ADC. Then you will configure the
ADC yourself, at the register level. It has a feature called
“auto-trigger” which is intended to provide perfectly consistent
timings. This is what you are looking for.